# How to take input from user to create markers on a video progress using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm newbie in java script and I want to create a video player in which user will click on video progress bar and  that time, a markers will place on it. Tell me where i'm wrong? below is my code:

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
<title>Video with markers</title>
<meta name="description" content=""/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/video-js.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/videojs.markers.min.css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/videojs-markers.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video 
    id="example_video_1" 
    class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
    controls 
    preload="auto" 
    autoplay
    width="640" 
    height="360"
    data-setup='{"width": 640, "height": 360}'>
  <source src="var/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>  

<script type="text/javascript">
  // load video object
  var video = videojs('example_video_1');

  //load markers
  video.markers({
    markers: [
      {time: 9.5, text: "this"},
      {time: 150,  text: "is"},
      {time: 250,text: "so"},
      {time: 370,  text: "cool"}
    ]
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling `seeked` event listener on your video object which will get you the current time the video has reached. Then all left is to add a marker at that time which you can do simply by calling `add` method on marker object.

Below is the modified code.

I have added cdn to make it work on my machine.it should work just fine in yours with relative path.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
 <title>Video with markers</title>
 <meta name="description" content=""/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
 <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs.markers.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.2/video.js"></script>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-markers/0.7.0/videojs-markers.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video 
   muted="muted" //added because i got an error of DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
   id="example_video_1" 
   class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
   controls 
   preload="auto" 
   autoplay
   width="640" 
   height="360"
   data-setup='{"width": 640, "height": 360}'>
   <source src="../RestAPI with Node/1.What is a RESTful API_ _ Creating a REST API with Node.js.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
   </video>  

 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // load video object
  var video = videojs('example_video_1');

  //load markers
 video.markers
 video.markers({
  markers: [
   {time: 9.5, text: "this"},
   {time: 150,  text: "is"},
   {time: 250,text: "so"},
   {time: 370,  text: "cool"}
 ]
});
  //listens to event whenever user jumps to a particular time
 video.on('seeked', function(event) {
  console.log("Seeked")
  console.log(event.target.currentTime) // get the currentTime of the video
  var currentTime = event.target.currentTime;
  video.markers.add([{ time: currentTime, text: "I'm added"}]); //add markers dynamically
 });
})

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!!!